# Language-Golf Proposal

Tags: discussion, tags

Da wir es hier nicht mit so vielen Fragen zu tun haben, möchte ich unsere spanische Schwesternseite als Vorbild nehmen und Translation-Golf vorschlagen: [Ursprüngliche Regeln hier](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592)

Laut [leginda.de](https://www.leginda.de/textlaenge-uebersetzungen/) sind englische Texte in der Regel etwa 10–15 % kürzer als eine deutsche Übersetzung. Jetzt können wir zeigen, dass wir im Deutschen nicht immer den längsten haben, sondern auch kürzer können … Moment!

Das Ganze soll sich nicht nur auf englischsprachige Originaltexte beziehen, jede Ausgangssprache ist willkommen – sollte aber ggf. eine möglichst originalgetreue englische Übersetzung mitbringen. Dies schließt auch Deutsch mit ein. Wäre doch mal spannend, einen Gesetzestext oder einen wissenschaftlichen Text gegolft zu sehen. Um es auch für nicht deutschsprachige Mitleser interessant zu gestalten, finde ich eine Übersetzung einer gegolften Antwort empfehlenswert – aber nicht verpflichtend.

Was haltet ihr von der Idee? Ich erstelle ein Community-Wiki für die Regeln als Antwort. Außerdem wäre ein [language-golf](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-golf)-Tag an der Stelle super.

Als Beispiel diene der erste Absatz des Wikipedia Artikel des Tages [Theorie der endlichen Kugelpackungen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorie_der_endlichen_Kugelpackungen)

Beispiel:

> Die Theorie der endlichen Kugelpackungen ist ein Gebiet der Mathematik, welches sich mit der Frage beschäftigt, wie eine endliche Anzahl gleich großer Kugeln optimal, also möglichst platzsparend, verpackt werden kann. Endliche Kugelpackungen sind erst in den letzten Jahrzehnten mathematisch genauer untersucht worden. László Fejes Tóth hat dazu wichtige Grundsteine gelegt.

Gegolft:

> Die Theorie der endlichen Kugelpackungen sucht optimale Packungen gleich großer Kugeln. Das wurde erst in den letzen Dekaden genauer untersucht. László Fejes Tóth machte viele Grundlagen.

Comment: Ich finde das Beispiel macht schon deutlich, worauf das hinausläuft: Unlösbare Meinungskonflikte. Das sieht ja wie ein Lexikoneintrag aus, und die gegolfte Version macht weder deutlich, dass es um Mathematik geht, noch, dass Platzsparen das Ziel ist. Es könnte sich auch um ein Ingenieursproblem handeln, wo es um Stabilität oder Materialkosten geht.

Comment: Hm, schade, dass es hier nicht ankommt. Auf der spanischen Seite sieht es sehr spaßig aus.

Comment: Ja, 0:2 votes, die große Masse ist dagegen. :) Ich kann leider kein Spanisch, um mir selbst ein Urteil zu bilden.

Comment: Kann spaßig sein. Mein erster Gedanke zu dem Beispiel ist: Ich gewinne jedesmal mit "Das Wort." Denn mit jeder "Zusammenfassung" lasse ich Details weg. Und zu bestimmen, ob eine Zusammenfassung noch das Original vollständig wiedergibt UND die Weglassungen - erscheint mir schwer entscheidbar (§6). Mangels Spanisch-Kenntnissen kann ich das von dort nicht wirklich beurteilen.

Comment: [Hier gibt es eine spanische Edition mit Übersetzungen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31604/translation-golf-xlviii-were-sorry-to-see-you-go)

Answer (score 0):

## **Regeln und Richtlinien**

> **§ 0**
>   Das letzte Wort hat immer OP. Besonders falls Zweifel bestehen, ob eine der nachfolgenden Regeln eingehalten/verletzt worden ist. OP bestimmt außerdem nach dem Ablauf der Zeit den Gewinner (= akzeptierte Antwort).
>
> **§ 1**
>   Die Standarddauer einer Runde language-golf dauert eine Woche. Dabei ist maximal eine Spielinstanz erlaubt, also keine Parallelrunden.
>
> **§ 2**
>   Offensichtlich muss die Übersetzung dem Original entsprechen und darf nicht zu stark davon abweichen. Dies setzt voraus, dass das Original nicht zu kompliziert sein darf und einfach genug zu verstehen sein sollte. Im Zweifel sei auf Regel 0 verwiesen.
>
> **§ 3**
>   Alle Ausgangssprachen (inklusive Deutsch) sind willkommen. Falls die Ausgangssprache nicht Englisch ist, wäre eine Übersetzung ins Englische wünschenswert (nicht verpflichtend), um der internationalen stackexchange community gerecht zu werden.
>
> **§ 4**
>   OP muss immer zunächst selbst einen Übersetzungsvorschlag ins Deutsche einbringen, damit language-golf nicht als Ausrede für translation-requests genutzt werden kann. Dies kann eine mit Absicht umständliche Übersetzung sein, damit andere Nutzer noch eine Chance haben mitzuspielen und ggf. in Spoilertags gesetzt werden, um Mitspieler nicht zu beeinflussen.
>
> **§ 5**
>   Die Übersetzung mit den wenigsten Zeichen gewinnt und muss von OP als Antwort akzeptiert werden, nach Ablauf einer Woche. Als je 1 Zeichen gelten die Klein- und Großbuchstaben, Umlaute, `ß`, Ziffern oder "fremde" Buchstaben, wenn es sich um Xenolizismen handelt. Satz- und Leerzeichen werden nicht gezählt. `Man reich' mir die Crème fraîche!` zählt somit als 26 Zeichen.
>
> **§ 6**
>   Verwendete Wörter müssen im [Duden](http://duden.de) oder [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/) zu finden sein. Komposita, welche dort nicht zu finden sind, müssen dem gesunden Menschenverstand unterliegen (Oberweserdampfschifffahrtskapitäns… gehört sicher nicht dazu). Umgangssprache und Dialekte sind erlaubt. Dialekte sind aber nicht mischbar; d. h., ein bayrischer Text darf keinen norddeutschen Slang verwenden. Gegebenenfalls sollte bei starken Dialektformen erklärt werden, was es damit auf sich hat.
>
> **§ 7**
>   Abkürzungen sind nicht erlaubt.
>
> **§ 8**
>   Wörter ohne erkennbares Geschlecht dürfen in beide Formen übersetzt werden. (teacher kann also als Lehrer oder Lehrerin betrachtet werden.)
>
> **§ 9**
>   Antworten dürfen während der gesamten Spieldauer bearbeitet werden. OP ist dazu ermutigt, Spieler auf regelverletzende Beiträge hinzuweisen.

Comment: Wer oder was ist OP, Originalposter? Muss es nicht immer "der/das OP" heißen, wo nur "OP" steht? Auch wenn ich insgesamt dagegen bin, schlage ich vor Regel 5 so zu ändern, dass Whitespace als Zeichen gilt, so dass man mit wc leicht prüfen kann, wie lang ein Text ist, ohne tr oder sed vorzuschalten. In §6 kenne ich zwar den Begriff Oberdampf nicht, sehe aber nicht ein, was daran problematisch ist. Umgangssprache u. Dialekte würde ich ausschließen. §8: "The teacher is responsible for the class." Teacher heißt Lehrer und das Geschlecht des Wortes ist leicht zu erkennen: m.

Comment: §9: Dieser widerspricht dem sonstigen Gefüge von SE fundamental. Um einen Sieger zu küren ist ein Ultimo sinnvoll, aber wieso sollten nicht neue Beiträge außer Konkurrenz erlaubt sein? Ein neuer Nutzer könnte Befriedigung daraus ziehen, dass er zwar nicht das Bummerl für "akzeptierte Antwort" mit der Vergütung von 5 Punkten erhält, aber was die Upvotes betrifft an allen anderen vorbeizieht.

Comment: Das widerspricht doch nicht, einen neuen Beitrag zu schreiben. Aber du musst quasi nicht "einloggen". Wenn Dir nach Absenden noch auffällt, dass du noch etwas tweaken kannst, dann ist das erlaubt.

Comment: Achso, also wie bei Code Golf. Und was ist mit den anderen Fragen? Oberweser ist ja noch naheliegender als Oberdampf. Was ist der Grund solche Konstrukte zu verbieten?

Comment: OP ist Originalposter. Ich hab mich an genderneutral versucht und wollte alles als OP schreiben, hat aber nicht so gut funktioniert. Whitespaces nur zu inkluden, damit das zählen einfacher wird, finde ich kein gutes Argument. Siehe z.B. [diese Seite](https://charcounter.com/en/) die so einen einfachen Service anbietet. Oberweserdampfschifffahrtskapitänskajüte ist ein ganz klares Fantasiewort. Wasserflaschendeckel steht bestimmt auch nicht unbedingt im Duden, aber halte ich für valider, als $1. The teacher kannst du auch mit Die Lehrerin übersetzen und wäre dann eben weiblich.